# Calculate and aggregate column depending on a value in another colum (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table consisting of stock trades. I need to calculate profit made by each trader (here one example, trader "Ben").

```
trader   position   quantity   tradeprice   marketprice
Ben      long          1          100          150
Ben      short        -1          105          150
```

The trick is that long positions are positive quantities while short positions are negative, thus slight modification for calculating the profit is required depending on the trade.

The logic is as follows:

Profit from long position is 50 (buy with price 100, sell to market with price 150).

Profit from short position is -45 (sell to market with price 105, buy from market with 150)

Total profit = 5

Spreadsheet way:

```
-1*(quantity*tradeprice) + marketprice = 50 / Long position profit

-1*(quantity*tradeprice) - marketprice = -45 / Short position profit
```

I need to add an additional column `Profit` for each trader.

Many thanks,

Comment: Does the quantity have the right sign on your two rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just conditional aggregation.  As you describe the problem:

```
select trader,
       sum(case when position = 'long' then (market_price - trade_price) * quantity
                when position = 'short' then (market_price - trade_price) * (- quantity)
           end)
from t
group by trader;
```

However, your sample data suggests:

```
select trader, sum( (market_price - trade_price) * quantity)
from t
group by trader;
```